# SOLR 4.x vs 3.x parsedquery differences

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solr4

I'm migrating from 3.x to 4.x and I'm running some queries to verify that everything works like before.
I've found however that the query "galaxy s3" is giving much less results. In 3.x numFound=1628, in 4.x numFound=70.

Here's the relevant schema part:

```
<fieldtype name="text_pt" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
   <analyzer type="index">
       <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="-" replacement="IIIHYPHENIII"/>
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="IIIHYPHENIII" replacement="-"/>
       <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="false" words="portugueseStopWords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.BrazilianStemFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
       <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="-" replacement="IIIHYPHENIII"/>
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="IIIHYPHENIII" replacement="-"/>
       <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />           
       <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="portugueseSynonyms.txt" expand="true"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" protected="protwords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="false" words="portugueseStopWords.txt"/>
       <filter class="solr.BrazilianStemFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

The synonyms involved in this query are:

```
siii, s3
galaxy, galax
```

My default search operator is AND (in both versions, even if it's deprecated in 4.x), and the output of the debug is:

SOLR 3.x

```
<str name="parsedquery">+(title_search_pt:galaxy title_search_pt:galax) 
+MultiPhraseQuery(title_search_pt:"(sii s3 s) 3")</str>
```

SOLR 4.x

```
<str name="parsedquery">+((title_search_pt:galaxy title_search_pt:galax)/no_coord) 
+(+title_search_pt:sii +title_search_pt:s3 +title_search_pt:s +title_search_pt:3)/str>
```

The weird thing is that it does not return results like 'galaxy s3'. This is the debug query:

no match on required clause (+title_search_pt:sii +title_search_pt:s3 +title_search_pt:s +title_search_pt:3) 
(NON-MATCH) Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s), **no match on required clause (title_search_pt:sii)** 
(NON-MATCH) no matching term 
(MATCH) weight(title_search_pt:s3 in 1834535) 
(MATCH) weight(title_search_pt:s in 1834535) 
(MATCH) weight(title_search_pt:3 in 1834535)

How is that sii is *required* when it should be OR'ed with s and s3 ?

The analysis output shows that sii has token position 2, like it's synonyms, like so:

```
galaxy  sii 3
galax   s3
        s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason we don't know, the autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" was not being honored in SOLR 3.x, but in 4.x it was.

To mantain the same behaviour we see in the parsedquery we had to switch the flag to true.

Thanks to Chris Hostetter in the SOLR mailing lists for providing me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `preserveOriginal="1"` in `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` in the `query` section. This option is for indexing only (if you use AND operator).

Comment: Thanks, will consider it. However that was not the cause of the problem.